# Component is not registered when adding variable to a dialog in MFC

Tags: mfc, com, activex, atl

I made my own ATL Control and then add it to an MFC project. Now I am trying to add a variable to the control and trying to add value to my control properties and call it's method. However, when I'm done adding a variable, there is an error:

> Component [GUID] is not registered

[image: Error dialog]

I have checked in the registry and I can see the GUID there:

[image: Registry editor screenshot]

What should I do to fix this bug?

Comment: Visual Studio's resource editor is pretty much broken to the point of being useless. This could be an issue with the IDE rather than your installation. Try running the application to determine that. If the IDE is indeed correct, then maybe you haven't installed the OCX using the correct bitness (32 vs. 64).

Comment: I v'e try to build my ActiveX in both X86 and x64 and it worked. I can add variable. How ever. My libraries I used to create ActiveX control is just support for x64. Anh I just want to create x64 ActiveX control. So how can I tell the app just run in x64 and forget checking register in x86.

Comment: If you want your program execute as an x64 binary, then simply compile it as an x64 binary. You don't have to tell anyone to stop checking for anything. A 64-bit binary isn't going to be checking for available 32-bit ActiveX controls. This is, presumably, not about *your* code at all. It is about Visual Studio that seemingly wants to have ActiveX controls for a specific architecture in its design-time dialog editor. If you aren't already, try using VS 2022. It's dialog editor is still the same garbage, but at least VS 2022 is a 64-bit application now, so that may solve *that* issue.

Comment: I just simply compile my ActiveX Control (ATL) in x64 and my app in x64 but the MFC still checking if my ActiveX Control in x86 has been registered or not. And it prevent me adding variable to the control. And I am using VS 2022 actually

Comment: In that case you can either work around the issue by compiling a 32-bit version of the ActiveX control and registering it, or file a defect report with Visual Studio. The latter is usually going to result in Microsoft acknowledging the defect, and then, a few years later, closing the defect report because there's not enough developers asking to have it fixed. The strategy of prioritizing defects based on clients asking rather than severity is part of why the resource editor is in the shape it is today. This doesn't look like something *we* can change, sorry.

Comment: Thank for your advise. I can't not find other solutions for this issue also.